# Jooq jsonb_array_elements equivalent

Tags: postgresql, jooq

I'm looking for the function in jooq to use postgres's `jsonb_array_elements` function. I'm trying to convert this query to jooq:

```
select
  s.id as shipment_id,
  so.id as sales_order_id,
  s_item -> 'productId' as product_id,
  s_item -> 'sub_items' as sub_items
from shipment s
  join sales_order so
    on s.sales_order_id = so.id,
  jsonb_array_elements(s.items) AS s_item
where s.status = 'READY'
```

I looked in the [json functions sections of the jooq docs](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/column-expressions/json-functions/), but didn't find it there.

Is there a workaround or different way of expressing `jsonb_array_elements` in jooq?

Answer (score 0):

jOOQ doesn't support this function yet. You can either use:

- [`JSON_TABLE`](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/table-expressions/json-table-function/). This is a SQL standard that is not yet supported by PostgreSQL 15, but probably will be, soon. It works almost like your function. jOOQ emulates it using `jsonb_path_query_first`
- [Plain SQL templating](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/plain-sql-templating/)

In the latter case, just use:

```java
Table<?> table = DSL.table("jsonb_array_elements({0})", s.ITEMS);
```